# Working on a small project dealing with motion detection and sending alerts if displacement exceeds certain boundary.is it possible to implement yolo?

Tags: opencv, face-detection, yolo

This is the first mini project I am working on and I have been searching for some information regarding yolo. I want to know if we could train yolo to recognise objects in a real time webcam and set up a boundary (not to be confused with the boundary boxes) that sends out a simple alert if the so called object (in our case, a face) goes out of the boundary.

This is my first time asking here and I don't know if it is appropriate to do so. please let me know and I will be reading APIs related to motion detection. If there are any suggestions, please do give them.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this open source CCTV solution called https://shinobi.video/. I used it once to do motion detection and I think it could be much easier for you than building something from scratch.

Here are some articles they have that sound related to what you are trying to do:

- https://hub.shinobi.video/articles/view/JtJiGkdbcpAig40
- https://hub.shinobi.video/articles/view/xEMps3O4y4VEaYk

Comment: Thank you I will start with them right away